# Invalid Use of Null - Access 2013 VBA

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a loop that goes through using ADO to collect information from one table to populate another.

When I get to record 11096 I get a run time error. 
"Run-Time error 94:
 Invalid Use of Null"

This is whats highlighted

```
invDate = DateSerial(rstDe![Year], rstDe![Month], rstDe![Date]) ' Coverts Year, Month, and Day, to a date format.
```

If I hover over it it will reveal "7/19/2015", so why it thinks it's null?

O opened the table that rstDe refers to and went to record 11096, it looks fine. It contains the exact same number and format as the records above it.

Comment: `rstDe![Date]`? `Day`, perhaps?

Comment: no, the person who fills out the original information used date for day. I think there is missing line numbers in the original table. Because ignoring the whole statement gives me 11104 records in each table but mine ends 8 lines shorter. I'm gonna look into a fix... 11000 records is a pain to look through

Comment: Okay, so there must have been missing line numbers. Just solved  it with "If Not IsNull(rstDe![Year])" before the expression

Answer (score 0):

This is Solved.

There must have been skipping of lines in the original table causing me to see the wrong information when checking for myself why it was throwing a null error.

Just added a check before the date function"

```
If Not IsNull(rstDe![Year]) Then
  invDate = DateSerial(rstDe![Year], rstDe![Month], rstDe![Date]) ' Coverts Year, Month, and Day, to a date format.
  rstAr![Invoiced Date] = invDate
  rstAr![Outstanding Days] = (Date - invDate)
End If
```